# How to resolve the Power BI API token issue in the Azure ADFS Setup?

Tags: python, api, azure-active-directory, powerbi, adfs

The code was working fine until we have setup the federated Azure AD (SSO). More info on this link.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/01/22/accessing-the-power-bi-apis-in-a-federated-azure-ad-setup/

The source code is developed in python.

```
def token():

    username,password = login() #get login
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'scope': 'openid',
        'resource': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        'client_id': '******',
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'
    r = requests.post(endpoint, data=data)
    data = r.json()
    access_token = data['access_token']
    headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +access_token}
    return headers

Error:
    access_token = data['access_token']
    KeyError: 'access_token'
```

Does anyone had this issue and resolved it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is by default Azure AD will block ROPC flow for a Federated account. This flow only works if you are using a cloud account (onmicrosoft.com domain) for security reasons. If you need to authenticate with a Federated account, it's better if you use the ADAL library. We have an ADAL Java library here. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens-with-username-and-password

Also, please note that:

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
>   more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
>   requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
>   risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
>   flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Reference:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34108